# Fileupload cannot find file

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise

When I click on upload button it says that my fileupload does not contain a file. Why that? Did I miss something in my code?

```
                //Add profilepic to SP list
                SPList myProfileDocList = web.Lists.TryGetList("Employee documents");

                SPListItem profileDocListItem = myProfileDocList.Items.Add();
                profileDocListItem["Title"] = strUserName;

                if (FileUploadEmployeeDoc.PostedFile != null && FileUploadEmployeeDoc.HasFile)
                {
                    Stream fStream = FileUploadEmployeeDoc.PostedFile.InputStream;
                    var profPicContents = new byte[fStream.Length];
                    fStream.Read(profPicContents, 0, (int)fStream.Length);
                    fStream.Close();
                    fStream.Dispose();
                    SPAttachmentCollection profileDocAttachment = profileDocListItem.Attachments;
                    string profPicFileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadEmployeeDoc.FileName);

                    profileDocAttachment.Add(profPicFileName, profPicContents);
                }

                profileDocListItem.Update();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sir, it would be great if you could provide some more information about the problem. What are you trying to do? In which context?
Thanks!